Apache Poi. How do I center a table in a Word document?
There are lots of answers about how to center the contents of a cell in a table.  But I want to center the entire table.
When I create a table like this:
    XWPFTable table = doc.createTable(1,rowSize);
    table.removeBorders()
    table.setWidth("80.00%")

It's automatically left justified.  I know that for text I create a paragraph, create a run, add a CT object and a PR object and set the hAlign there.  The XWPFTable has similar methods:
    CTTbl cttbl = table.getCTTbl()
    CTTblPr cTTblPr = cttbl.addNewTblPr()

But I don't see anything in the JavaDoc for the CTTblPr which has anything to do with horizontal alignment.

Current Apache POI version  5.2.5 provides XWPFTable.setTableAlignment. It sets TableRowAlign.
Complete Example:
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordTableAligned {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Text before table...");

  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(1, 3);
  table.setWidth("50%");
  
  table.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.CENTER);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Text after table...");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordTableAligned.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}

Result:


To answer the question about what to set using the underlying CT-classes, have a look at what XWPFTable -> public void setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign tra)is doing. It gets or adds CTJcTable (table justification) from CTTblPr. Then it sets value of STJcTable.Enum which is either LEFT, RIGHT or CENTER.

Axel.  Thank you so much.  I really appreciate your assistance.
